# Is it possible to cast one object into the type of a 2nd object without knowing either type?

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I have a simple converter which checks if an object is equal to whatever parameter I pass it. My problem is that the converter parameter always gets passed as string and value always gets passed as object. To compare them properly I need to cast the parameter as the same type as the value. Is there a way I could cast the type of one object to the type of another without knowing either types beforehand?

```
public class IsObjectEqualParameterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null && parameter == null)
            return true;

        if (value == null)
            return false;

        // Incorrectly returns False when the ConverterParameter is an integer
        // Would like to try and cast parameter into whatever type value before checking equality
        // Something like: return value.Equals((parameter as value.GetType()));
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And example usage would be something like:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Index, ConverterParameter=0, Converter={StaticResource IsObjectEqualParameterConverter}}" />
```

Comment: If both `value` and `parameter` are integers, it should be fine. Could you give an example of it failing?

Comment: ConverterParameters get passed as strings, so when I enter 0 it is reading it as "0" and returning false.

Comment: Right - it would be helpful to make that clear in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
parameter = Convert.ChangeType(parameter, value.GetType());
```

This will only work when the true type of the `parameter` variable implements `IConvertible` (all primitive types do, plus string).  So it will do string conversions to primitive types:

```
csharp> Convert.ChangeType("1", typeof(int));
1
csharp> Convert.ChangeType("1", typeof(int)).GetType();
System.Int32
```

And vice-versa:

```
csharp> Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(string));
"1"
csharp> Convert.ChangeType(1, typeof(string)).GetType();
System.String
```

Comment: What window are you typing csharp> ... into to get results? That looks like the F# style window.

Comment: Thank you, that works great! I used a slightly modified version since I didn't know my types in advance (it is not always an int/string that gets passed into here) `parameter = System.Convert.ChangeType(parameter, value.GetType());`

Comment: @Rachel: Isn't that exactly the code that I gave you in the first code block?  The latter two blocks were intended only as examples of `ChangeType`'s behavior.

Comment: @myermian: It's Mono's interactive C# shell.

Comment: yes it is, sorry I was in a rush and somehow missed reading the first line of your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Reflections for this purpose:

```
using System.Reflection; 
int a = 10;
            string str = "10";
            Type a_type = a.GetType(), str_type = str.GetType();
            try
            {
                if (Convert.ChangeType((object)a, str_type).Equals(str))
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Can't to cast one type to other
            }
```

If you change types of variables, this code throws exception and notice you that you have tried to cast 'uncastable' types.

Comment: You do not need `using System.Reflection;` for any part of this code.  Further, you obtain `a_type` and never use it.